# How to get the country code based on country id in magento 2

Tags: magento2.2, country-regions

I wish to get the country code based on country id in checkout page .
I have the country id, How do i pass it to get country code in magento 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Block file,

```
   public function __construct(
            \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
        ) {
            $this->_countryFactory = $countryFactory;
        }

    public function getCountryCode($countryId){    
        $country = $this->_countryFactory->create()->load($countryId);
        return $country->getCode();
    }
```

Call like below

```
$block->getCountryCode($countryId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not very much sure about your query.

here is my suggestions may help you.

country_code has two types in the directory_country table.
1)iso2_code and 2) iso3_code

Whereas, iso2_code and country_id is similar.
If you want to get 3 digits of country_code, then proceed with iso3_code.

Like this, $country->getData('iso3_code')

```
protected $_country;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Country $country
) {
    $this->_country = $country;
}

public function getCountryname() {
    $countryCollection = $this->_country->getCollection();
    foreach ($countryCollection as $country) {
       $countryId = $country->getCountryId();
       $iso3Code = $country->getData('iso3_code');
    }
    echo $countryId;
}
```